# Drug which lets you forget everything

Tags: chemistry

We all know how the story starts:

> He woke up in strange room, not remembering who he was or how did he got to the room. But that was not his problem. Problem was the first writing he saw: "HELLO, I WANT TO PLAY A GAME"

The thing is, what kind of drug could Joe Average eat to let him forget almost everything?

And if you cannot be drugged to forget your own name, what drug would let you forget the past? (And as long to the past as possible).

Bonus points: What would be side effect of such drug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Most amnesiac drugs only work while they are in your system, making it so that new memories can't be recorded, without messing with old stored memories. This is really useful for anesthetic, since if someone is having open heart surgery you really don't want them to remember anything afterward.
One of these drugs that has been misused is Rohypnol.

There are a few drugs that are in the highly experimental stage, meaning they have never been tested on humans, which can wipe out past memories.

(Un)fortunately, since they've never been used on people, we don't really know what the effects would be.

a zeta inhibitory peptide [(ZIP)](http://scienceblogs.com/purepedantry/2007/08/20/the-amnesia-drug-frightening-b/) is a drug that inhibits the protein called PKC zeta, which is needed to maintain long term memories. There is a lot still left to learn about this area, but it looks like it would erase past memories, [while allowing the subject to learn new things](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1074742714002081). How much stuff gets erased is unknown. So it could work for your story, or the guy could end up as a mental infant again, but it'll probably be many years before we know which outcome is most likely.

Comment: We conducted human tests last month. if you don't remember, then the drug worked perfectly.

Comment: So open heart surgery could be a horrendously painful experience and no one would know?

Comment: @wedstrom Technically speaking, all surgery is painful, but the anesthesia blocks the signals. The amnesiac is for just in case the the anesthesia gets light. Those aren't dreams you want. I have a friend who's a nurse. He was helping on a rectal endoscopy, where the doctor "was just ramming it in there" in his words, and the anesthetized patient was showing signs of experiencing discomfort. After the surgery he was talking to the patient, asking how he felt, and the guy said something like "Wow, that was easy, I thought might be painful." If only he knew...

Comment: Interesting.  What's the difference between an anaesthetic, and a combination of an amnesiac drug (so you don't remember afterwards) and a powerful relaxant (so you cannot struggle and injure yourself). I'm hoping that there *is* a difference ....

Comment: @nigel222 There is a difference. Local anesthetics bind to the sodium channel and block nerve impulses and stop all feeling. General anesthetics are generally breathed in and will induce unconsciousness, may or may not be combined with an amnesiac, and can have side effects. Mussel relaxers paralyze skeletal mussels, and are sometimes used after anesthesia to make things easier. Amnesiacs like Propofol (milk of amnesia) are used when you don't want the danger of knocking someone out, but don't want them remembering it later (endoscopy). The patient is awake, but wont remember.

Comment: It seems that this actually doesn't answer the specific portion of the question where the subject can *eat* something to make him forget. The ZIP can't get to the brain from the digestive system or the blood stream. It would have to be injected directly into the central nervous system via the spine or through the skull.

Comment: @Samuel So the guy eats/drinks a drug like rohypnol, is thrown into the back of a van, taken somewhere, injected with the ZIP, and then the fun begins. I don't think there are any drugs that can be taken orally that reliably remove past memories while leaving the subject able to function cognitively so as to be able to handle "playing a game". He could make one up, or use a nano bot to deliver the drug to the brain and inject it in the right place. Could also use external memory blocking like hypnosis, brain surgery, or something else to cut off access to that information.

Comment: Incidentally for medical reasons I've had both endoscopy and colonoscopy with no anesthesia or pain medication.  They're both thoroughly unpleasant and painful without the anesthesia and pain relief but tolerable.  I know that I started moaning in pain from the endoscopy and the only relief they could give me was stroking my back in consolation.  It meant a lot.  As for the amnesiacs (such as Versed), they often also possess anti-anxiety effects too - so that's a win-win combination for the anesthetist.

Comment: @Jim2B Personally I'd find another doctor with modern medicine... :)  I've had an endoscopy, and I believe they used Propofol. I don't remember anything, and at the time had assumed I was unconscious, but now I realize I wasn't... It's almost creepy in a way, but not enough to want to go without.